# Difficulty converting a numpy array to a tensor. Issues using tf.convert_to_tensor and .to(device)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, torch

I'm trying to convert a numpy array to a tensor and I'm running into a lot of problems. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to replace a value in a tensor with its indices, so I am doing this:

```
pose_body = np.zeros([1,63])
pose_body[0,0] = 0.2
pose_body = tf.convert_to_tensor(pose_body)
pose_body = pose_body.to(comp_device)
```

I need to have a 63long tensor of zeros and I would like to be able to easily change the indices where 0.2 is put in.
As of right now this pose_body tensor looks like this:

tf.Tensor(
[[0.2 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]], shape=(1, 63), dtype=float64)

comp device is defined like this:

```
comp_device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

When I try to convert the tensor without `.to(comp_device)` I get the error of:

**TypeError: expected Tensor as element 1 in argument 0, but got tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor**

I get the same error except "but got numpy.ndarray" if I do not convert the array to a tensor. This makes me believe the tensor isn't really being converted into the tensor I need.

When `.to(comp_device)` is included I get this error:

**AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'to'**

I think these problems stem from the fact that converting to a tensor creates an EagerTensor (?). I am adapting someone else's code and it works perfectly when the tensor is created like this:

```
pose_body = torch.full([1,63],0.2).to(comp_device)
```

This correct pose_body tensor looks like this:

tensor([[0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000,
0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.2000]],
device='cuda:0')

I'm wondering if anyone has any advice, I've only been programming in python for a few months. Since I'm so new to this I think I'm probably missing a simple way to make the tensor I want to write look like the one that works. Let me know if anymore information is needed. I'm running python3 in jupyter notebook.

Comment: You are mixing Tensorflow and Pytorch code. This is a recipe for disaster. You should pick one framework and stick with it; as you can see they do not interact well.

Comment: I see, I had no idea. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you work in PyTorch than conversion is as easy as `torch.FloatTensor(pose_body)`. Conversion for the Tensorflow should be similarly simple if you pay attention to data types (for example, don't try to make integer tensor out of float array).